# HDF5 compilation in 16.04 ubuntu (Syntax error)

Tags: c++, syntax-error, hdf5, ubuntu-16.04

I installed libhdf5-dev package for starting developement with HDF5. It installed properly.

However, I am not able to compile any code, it gives syntax error in some of the header files. Below is the code and the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<H5File.h>
#include<H5Cpp.h>
#include<H5FaccProp.h>
#include <H5FcreatProp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace H5;

int main(){
  H5File file( "seq.h5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY, FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT, FileAccPropList::DEFAULT );
  cout <<"print compiled"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
$ g++ Main.cpp -I /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ -lhdf5_serial
In file included from Main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/H5File.h:29:24: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
 class H5_DLLCPP H5File : public H5Location, public CommonFG {
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/hdf5/serial/hdf5.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/hdf5/serial/H5Include.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/hdf5/serial/H5Cpp.h:20,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/H5public.h:170:20: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
 H5_GCC_DIAG_OFF(long-long)
                    ^
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/H5public.h:170:20: error: expected declaration before end of line
```

Ofcourse, this code is not much useful as such. 
I believe this is a problem with hdf5 header files. When I checked into H5public.h this is what I see, which looks perfectly correct.

```
169 #if H5_SIZEOF_LONG_LONG >= 8
170 H5_GCC_DIAG_OFF(long-long)
171 typedef unsigned long long      hsize_t;
172 typedef signed long long        hssize_t;
173 H5_GCC_DIAG_ON(long-long)
174 #       define H5_SIZEOF_HSIZE_T H5_SIZEOF_LONG_LONG
175 #       define H5_SIZEOF_HSSIZE_T H5_SIZEOF_LONG_LONG
176 #else
177 #   error "nothing appropriate for hsize_t"
178 #endif
```

Comment: Include H5Cpp.h first.

Comment: Got it `g++ Main.cpp -I /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ -lhdf5_serial -lhdf5_cpp` was missing a cpp linker

Comment: That's true, but the error you have provided is a compiler error, not a linker error.

Comment: Yes. I agree. Sometimes errors in C++ are weird. I guess it tried to compile it as C lib instead of C++ and hence the syntax error. A full explanation as to why this happened is bound to blow my mind.   :D